# Защищённая и закрытая область видимости свойств и методов

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы выводило и защищённое и закрытое свойство?

```
class MyClass
{
   protected $prot = "text1";
   private $priv = "text2";
   function printText()
   {
       echo $this->prot;
       echo $this->priv;
   }
}
$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->prot;
echo $obj->priv;
$obj->printText();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Свойства и методы отмеченные как защищённые или `protected`, доступны только самому исходному классу и его наследникам.

Этот модификатор обычно используется, если предполагается, что классы наследники должны иметь доступ к определённым членам базового класса, но при этом доступ к ним из любых других классов (`public`) не желателен.

Некоторые [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected) использования в PHP можно посмотреть на англоязычном SO.

Закрытые члены класса (`private`) доступны только внутри него самого.

Поэтому в Вашем случае это:

```
$obj->printText();
```

Отработает нормально. А, это:

```
echo $obj->prot;
echo $obj->priv;
```

Выдаст ошибку.